# Combine queries at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I want to ask If is possible to combine SQL queries at runtime.

Lets say I have a stored procedure with parameters `@type(int)`, `@name(varchar(50))=null` and `@dept(varchar(50))=null`.

Now I have a query `Select * from Employees`.

My question is can I dynamically add something like `where name = @name` when @type = 1 or `where dept = @dept` when @type = 2

Comment: How are you calling this stored procedure? Is this a SQL question or C# question? It is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write

```
where (@type = 1 and name = @name) or (@type = 2 and dept = @dept)
```

Comment: Thanks Archil, but how about if the default query is `Select * from Employees where name = @name` and it involves and adding a query like `and dept = @dept`?

Comment: @Jay sorry, I do not exactly understand problem there. Do you want to add dept condition only when dept is not null or whitespace?

Comment: all I need is a way you can dynamically add this query `and dept = @dept` to the default query `Select * from Employees where name = @name` when @type (as illustrated above) = 2 or some other condition

Comment: My example does exactly that, `(@type = 2 and dept = @dept)` means - when `@type = 2`, check for dept to be equal to @dept. Otherwise, leave as it is

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.
Following link shows how to use parameters in Stored procedures. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-to-write-a-Stored-procedure-in-Sql

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADO.Net then read [Populating A DataSet from a DataAdapter (ADO.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx) and [Generating Commands With CommandBuilders (ADO.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx).